# Does tmux on cygwin have a limit of 16 panes

Tags: cygwin, tmux, tmuxinator

I am trying out tmux on cygwin.  It seems like there is limit of 16 panes.  Is this a hard limit?  Can I increase the limit via some settings?

Comment: How are you trying to create the panes? If there is such a limit, it would appear to be specific to cygwin, which doesn't make a lot of sense. Also, this is probably better suited to unix.stackexchange.com. Post there with a description of how to trigger this limit, along with whatever error message you get.

Comment: I tried two approaches.  Normally, I am using tmuxinator to create the windows and panes.  For this 16-pane limit problem, I was splitting the panes manually.

Comment: I'm not sure if there could be a limit in older versions; I had no trouble creating 20 panes in a window in `tmux` 2.6 on macOS.

Comment: Humm... I just tried manually splitting and now and I can go many more beyond 16 panes -- I have no idea what the issue is.  I will add more detail next time I see the issues.